# error on client side of web app: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in
```

I'm using a python web application (Adagios, a Nagios configuration tool).
When attempting a certain operation on the client side browser I get the above error.

The client side is Ubuntu 14.04, server side is debian 8. Browser is Firefox or Chrome.
both show:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Before I dive into the code, are there any OS level things to try?

Here's the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/adagios/adagios/views.py", line 43, in wrapper
    result = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/adagios/adagios/objectbrowser/views.py", line 191, in edit_object
    c['form'] = PynagForm(pynag_object=my_object, initial=my_object._original_attributes)
  File "/opt/adagios/adagios/objectbrowser/forms.py", line 312, in __init__
    self.fields[field_name] = self.get_pynagField(field_name,  css_tag="inherited")
  File "/opt/adagios/adagios/objectbrowser/forms.py", line 418, in get_pynagField
    _('%(inherited_value)s (inherited from template)') % {'inherited_value': smart_str(inherited_value)}
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Hypothesis: `_('%(inherited_value)s (inherited from template)')` returns an encoded byte string containing a non-ASCII byte, but `smart_str(inherited_value)` produced a `unicode` object. What language was loaded to satisfy the `_(..)` gettext call may well depend on how adagios handles i18n; they probably look at your browser's Accepted-Language header.

Comment: But if you merely installed Adagios and are not a developer on that project, then you are asking a support question best directed at the Adagios project. Stack Overflow is not a general software support site. File a bug with that project instead.

Comment: m.p.-  or course, the adagios forum was the 1st place i turned. no solution was forthcoming form there, so i turn to other alternatives in search of a solution.